# Python: split and re generate strings

Tags: python

I want to put ' --- ' after 3 characters and put ' -- ' after the next 3 characters of the given string.

For example, if the given string is `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR'`, then the output is
`'ABC --- DEF -- GHI --- JKL -- MNO --- PQR'`

```
def addpattern(string):
    result = ' --- '.join(string[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(string),3))
    return result
```

This code prints like
`ABC --- DEF --- GHI --- JKL --- MNO --- PQR`

but I want to change like `ABC --- DEF -- GHI --- JKL -- MNO --- PQR`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What if it is multiple of both 3 and 6 ?

Comment: If it is a multiple of 3 but not a multiple of 6 then, insert only ' --- '

Comment: What does it mean *the number of the alphabet is divided by a multiple of six*. Try to [edit] and be more clear

Comment: and if the number of alpabet is multiple of 6 then insert ' -- '

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "number"? the length of the whole string, or the position of a character in the string?

Comment: I think I questioned wrong.

Comment: print like this 'xxx --- xxx -- xxx --- xxx -- xxx --- xxx'

Comment: @mia You said you wanted the output to be `ABC --- DEF -- GHI -- JKL --- MNO -- PQR` That is just a typo right? After DEF and GHI are two hyphens and after that things get offset. Or is this what you want to happen?

Comment: @RedKnite I mean three alphabets - 'three' hyphens - three alphabets - 'two' hyphens - three alphabets - 'three' hyphen -three alphabets - 'two' hyphen.

the number of hyphen(-) is change everytime.
three - two - three - two - three - two - three - two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def addpattern(string):
    ret = ""
    grouped = [string[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]
    for index, value in enumerate(grouped):
        ret += value

        if index != len(grouped) - 1:
            if index % 2:
                ret += " --- "
            else:
                ret += " -- "
```

Generally using `str.join` is a good idea, but in this case it is too limited. A for loop works better here.